# Change text values to int in classification/clustering task

Tags: r, dataframe, cluster-analysis, data-manipulation

Having a task to make clustering in R with dataset, which contains categorical text values (like "blue", "red"). k-means algorithm though takes only numeric values, so I need to convert those text categories to int categories.  Is there any 1-line solution to it? or maybe some other?

```
         Attribute1 Attribute2                     Attribute1 Attribute2
Instance1  "blue"     "red"         =>  Instance1       1          2
Instance2  "green"    "blue"            Instance2       3          1
```

`a[,1] <- sapply(a[,1],switch,"blue"=1,"red"=2,"green"=3)`

makes the task, but for first column of "a" dataframe

```
x_num <- as.numeric(x)
```

makes different, but looks like it.

Comment: you can't do that, if you convert "blue", "red" to 1,2 you are implying some kind of order which I guess isn't the case?

Comment: you should do one-hot encoding, or try gower distance for clustering ,for e.g https://www.r-bloggers.com/clustering-mixed-data-types-in-r/

Comment: yes, thank you much. That was what I was looking for

Comment: glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

So, as we are making cluster analysis, we want to make our clusters as far from each other, as possible. the method I thought about in question
is too much straight forward, and will work bad (if implemented). the good solution is applying some distance metric that can handle mixed data types. 
The mentioned in comments is gower, which is universal. Jaccard distance also exists for binary categories. 
The exaple of gower solution (R):

```
library(cluster)
gower.dissimilarity.mtrx <- daisy(DataFrame, metric = c("gower"))
```

function here is `'daisy'`, though there is also `'dist'`, which makes sometheing same, but with euclidian method.
[more on topic](https://medium.com/@rumman1988/clustering-categorical-and-numerical-datatype-using-gower-distance-ab89b3aa90d9)